# ajax popup extender with aspx page inside iframe inside panel

Tags: ajax, modalpopupextender

I am trying to implement a popup login screen using ajaxpopupextender.

Is it possible to use an aspx page(which is the login page ) to show in the Panel using iframe?

Is there any advantage of using page instead of user control inside the panel? Does both gets loaded on parent page_load? considering faster page load Plase suggest which method to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUp" Style="display: none ;padding:3px;" runat="server"  >

 //Test.aspx page is a page which you want to show as a popup

    <iframe id="frame1" src="Test.aspx" style="overflow: auto;height:200px; width:                 100%;" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
  </asp:Panel>

        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" Y="50" runat="server" BehaviorID="mpe" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" BackgroundCssClass="bModal">
         </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```